# LAMP stack: all individual pieces load test great, but Wordpress still chokes on load

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, lamp

I have a LAMP stack running on AWS with a m3.large instance (2 vCPU, 8GB RAM, SSD). The performance is horrible when any decent load gets on it. If no load, then home page of the Wordpress site is ~2 seconds. If I test it with Apache Bench with a load of just 50-100, it gets into the ~12 second range for page load.

I have tested all the pieces individually and they seem to be fine. I Apache Bench tested an info.php page for 100 users and it came back at 0.2 seconds. I also used Mysqlslap to load test 100 users and it came back about 0.2 seconds.

I have memcached installed and have tried all sorts of various settings in php.ini, my.cnf, and httpd.conf, but nothing seems to do any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: What plugins are you using? Theme? Have you customised wordpress in any other ways? We need more information.

Comment: @Bulk It's actually a custom theme developed by another guy. I'm just setting the server up. It runs just fine on the server they're coming from, however it *is* a dedicated server. They want to leave that behind because it costs so much and go to AWS where it's cheaper.

Comment: Where is the database hosted? Is it connecting to a remote database ?

Comment: @LuckyBurger MySQL is installed on same machine, so localhost. When I load test the home page and it chokes, Apache spawns eat up 100% CPU but mysql stays low.

Comment: If a plain php page is having no issues the issue is almost certainly related to the database. Check the slow query log, also look at any network problems/congestion (if its not on the same server)

Answer (score 0):

Disable all plugins and see if that speeds up the response time. Then enable them one by one to find the issue. You can do this via the admin panel.

If you cannot access the admin panel, rename the plugin directory.